# SUM values when conditions met

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL Server table with the following data:

```
PRICE(decimal 9,2)   PRICETYPE(int)     EVENTDETAILID (int)

PRICE          PRICETYPE          EVENTDETAILID
------------------------------------------------
99                 1                    1
99                 1                    1
99                 1                    1
15                 0                    1
15                 0                    1
50                 1                    2
50                 1                    2
```

I want to `SUM` the `PRICE` of the results with the following conditions:

for each `EVENTDETAILID`, `SUM` every line with a `pricetype` is 0 and for every line per `EVENTDETAILID` pricetype is 1, then add it only 1 time.

For the above example the required output would be:

- 99 + 15 + 15 for `eventDetailId = 1`
- 50 for `eventDetailsId = 2`

I've tried the following but doesn't work as expected as I'm not able to add `PRICE` only once if `PRICETYPE` is 1:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(PRICE) 
FROM 
    ReservationDetails 
GROUP BY 
    eventDetail_id
```

Comment: Are the prices always the same for a given `EVENTDETAILID` where the `PRICETYPE` is 1?

Comment: Yes they are the same when PRICETYPE is 1. Pricetype 0 may or may not have the same PRICE. Eg. instead of 15 on the above example could be 99 as well.

Comment: Can you show the expected result in this particular example?

Comment: Yes i've already stated the expected output in the description above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may phrase this as an aggregation (`GROUP BY`) query over the event detail ID.  The sum can be broken into a conditional sum when the detail ID is 0, combined with the *maximum* price when the detail ID is 1.  Since you told us that the price is always the same when `PRICETYPE=1`, therefore we can choose any single value.

```
SELECT
    EVENTDETAILID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PRICETYPE = 0 THEN PRICE ELSE 0 END) +
    MAX(CASE WHEN PRICETYPE = 1 THEN PRICE ELSE 0 END) AS total
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    EVENTDETAILID
ORDER BY
    EVENTDETAILID;
```

[image]

### Demo